# Adding a root element to json

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I am generating a json string using NewtosoftJson using a table to format the the json. This is a simple key value pairs list and looks like:

```
public class items
{
    private string key = String.Empty;
    private string value = String.Empty;
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return key;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != key)
            {
                key = value;                  
            }
        }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.value)
            {
                this.value = value;                  
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

When a list is populated and then serialised I get this JSON:

```
"Items": [  
    {  
        "Key":"FirstValue",
        "Value":"One"
    },
    {  
        "Key":"SecondValue",
        "Value":"Two"
    },
    {  
        "Key":"ThirdValue",
        "Value":"Three"
    }
]
```

What I need to get is:

```
"customData": {
    "items": [
        {
            "Key":"FirstValue",
            "Value":"One"
        },
        {
            "Key":"SecondValue",
            "Value":"Two"
        },
        {
            "Key":"ThirdValue",
            "Value":"Three"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried creating a second class CustomData but can't see how to get the original JSON into the second class! Could you advice me on the correct way to construct the second class and method used to populate it please.

Comment: Please show how you're serializing the list to start with - where did the name "Items" come from, for example? (I'd also strongly recommend renaming your class to `Item` - it's a single item, with a key and a value. It also looks to me like you could use automatically implemented properties very simply.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an **anonymous object** and serialize that:

```
var objContainingItems = ... // your usual code

var customDataObj = new { customData = objContainingItems };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customDataObj);
```

This is the most convenient solution if all you are interested in is *serializing*.

If you also want to be able to *deserialize* it, then you will need to use a class as specified in the answer by @William Moore.

Comment: It is worth noting that outside the method/scope they are defined in anon objects are not type-safe - so if you need to use the object outside the method you define it you could introduce errors

Comment: Hi Peter, I have changed the code to reflect your recommendations (I was given the structure of the required json from the developer of the API!) and although the json doe's not have the 'item' root object the API that I am passing the json to is happy with the structure. Thanks to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `customData` and create a reference to the class `items` inside it.  Then serialise your `customData` class using Newtonsoft.Json rather than your `items` class.  So you will have:

```
public class CustomData 
{
    public items[] items; // I would rename the class items to item
}
```

Then you have an object of type `customData`, called `customData` which you pass into Newtonsoft.

You could then use the following to serialise/deserialise your data:

```
CustomData input = new CustomData();
input.items = []; // Whatever you have at the moment?

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account) //optionally set Formatting.Indented

CustomData deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomData>(json);
```

Comment: Hi Sorry I didn't desert this question I was pinned down on the phone! I will try the suggested methods and come back many thanks.

Comment: If you don't need to deserialize the object then @PeterB's answer is slightly more concise (below)